# Passing uint attribute to GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to pass a bunch of consecutive unsigned ints as attribute to my GLSL shader.

So far I came up with

```
s_number = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "number");

numberData = new GLuint[dotAmount];
for (GLuint i = 0; i < dotAmount; i++) {
    numberData[i] = i;
}

glGenBuffers(1, &vertBuf);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf);

glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        sizeof(dotAmount),
        numberData,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW
);
```

The rendering function is

```
glUseProgram(shader);

[..]

glEnableVertexAttribArray(s_number);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf);

glVertexAttribPointer(
        s_number,
        1,
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
        GL_FALSE,
        0,
        BUFFER_OFFSET(0)
);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, dotAmount);
```

I try to use the number in the vertex shader like this:

```
attribute uint number;
```

(The name 'vertBuf' is actually a bit misleading since it's not vertex data I want to pass)
I'm using OpenGL 3 and shader versions 1.3.

What I am trying to achieve is, I want the shaders to be executed `dotAmount` times. The positioning is done mathematically within the shader. But all I get is a blank screen...

I am quite sure that the problem does not lie in the shaders. I want to draw points, and if I put `gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` in the vertex shader, I assume it should draw something.

Comment: As an aside, if all you want is a sequence from 0 to dotAmount-1, you could just read the gl_VertexID (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_VertexID.xml). If you move to GLSL 1.4+, then you could use instanced rendering and gl_InstanceID instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the fragment shader to `gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);` This will make sure that the output color makes the fragment visible.

Also, You should have `gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);` (The reason is that gl_Position must be in homogenous coordinates, meaning that the first three components will be divided by the fourth.)

Comment: `gl_Position` does not set the color, but the clip space position. However, your point is still valid as a clip space point at (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) would lead to a division by zero and undefined NDC/screen coords.

Answer (score 38):

You are using the wrong API call to specify your vertex attribute pointer.

`glVertexAttribPointer (...)` is for floating-point vertex attributes. It will happily take the value of an integer data type, but ultimately this value will be converted to floating-point. This is why it has a parameter to control floating-point normalization. When normalization is enabled, an integer value you pass is adjusted using the type's range to make it fit within the normalized floating-point range: `[-1.0, 1.0]` (signed) or `[0.0, 1.0]` (unsigned); when disabled, an integer is effectively treated as if it were cast to a `GLfloat`.

In your case, you want neither behavior described above. In your vertex shader, your vertex attribute is not a floating-point type to begin with, so having OpenGL convert your vertex array data to floating-point will produce meaningless results.

What you need to do is use `glVertexAttribIPointer (...)`. Notice how this function lacks the boolean for normalization? It will pass your integer vertex data completely unaltered to your vertex shader, exactly what you want.

In summary:

1. `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` is good for supplying data to floating-point vertex attributes (i.e. `vec<N>`, `mat4`, `float`), and will do data-type conversion for you.
2. `glVertexAttribIPointer (...)` is specifically designed for integer attributes (i.e. `ivec<N>`, `{u}int`).

Comment: This didn't matter for the problem, but is a very good information!

Comment: I just want to take a moment to express my love for you. This answer solved all of my problems.

Comment: Very nice answer, this help me a lot